# cat Unix command directly from java, should not call shell Script

Tags: java, unix, runtime.exec

I have one question.
Is it possible to run unix command directly from java {not as a shell script} ? I saw ls command is directly executed the output viewed getting object of bufferedReader. Actually I want ** cat fil*.csv >> filAppended.csv ** run this command directly from java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The >> part of your command is not an argument to cat, but handled by the shell to do the output redirection.

You can access the output stream from the Process object returned by Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), and can then read from that and append it to the 'filAppended.csv'.

Comment: You mean I have to run 1st. cat fil*.csv after that have to append filAppended.csv by process buffered reader right?

Comment: Basically, yes. But if your command is really cat, then it makes no sense to run a command at all. It's much more reasonable to just read one file and write to another -- there's no need for an exec().

Comment: sorry I'm not understand in u said "there's no need for an exec(). "

Comment: Also the fil*.csv is a part of the schell.  You will have to do that in java also if you dont want to run a shell.